# Using DateDiff with with null value

Tags: c#, sql

I'm working in C# with an SQL statement below.

```
string ConsultDiff = 
  @"SELECT AVG(ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, Consult_Date, Start_Date),0)) 
     FROM patients 
    WHERE progression = 'CO' AND Plan_Type = 'New Patient' " + 
     Site + " " + Primary_Onc + " " + Type + " " + DateRange + "";
```

When there are no rows available due to the data filtering, it throws the error: 'Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types'. I think it is having a problem with the DATEDIFF section. I want it to show a value of 0 when there is a null value. It seems to still return a null value. The code works fine when there are actual rows to pull data from.
the code is called in the following part of c#:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(ConsultDiff, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            int countConsultDiff = Convert.ToInt32(cmd3.ExecuteScalar());
            lblConsulttoStart.Text = Convert.ToString(countConsultDiff);
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: what happen when you use COALESCE instead of ISNULL?

Comment: Hi, please show us the rest of the code. That looks like a c# error, not a database errro.

Comment: `ISNULL(AVG(...), 0)`. The *result* being `NULL` is the problem, not the values being aggregated.

Comment: Are you using output query parameters? That is a common response when an output query parameter holds DbNull. In which case you can check for DbNull before using it.

Comment: Append that to the original question.

Comment: I appended the code @RickHodder.

Comment: I think @bruno.almeida is on the right track, you're converting nothing into a string I think that might be your issue. When you debug, what line does it fail on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try make this:

```
var result = cmd3.ExecuteScalar();
int countConsultDiff = Convert.IsDBNull(result) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your database field  contain SQL NULL values when they are returned via a query due to which it is throwing Exception/Error  .You can check and use: `DBNull.Value` and incase it is returning Null value then do no "Select  or Execute the query " .
You need to check the returned value to ensure it is not DBNull.
You can  also allow null  by declare the variable as nullable types.

Answer (score 0):

You could use COALESCE.
I am not sure if bothe can be null or not but lets assume only ever 1 will be null, ou should get it from that.

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, COALESCE(Consult_Date, StartDate), COALESCE(Start_Date, Consult_Date)
```

So in the above, I believe if eitehr ar null, it will coealesce to the others value and hence the DATEDIFF Will be zero.

Hope it works and helps